# Reducing to list of object from object key and value

Tags: ramda.js

Given a previous Ramda groupBy to

```
{
    '2018-Q4': 2,
    '2019-Q1': 5
}
```

How can I map this to

```
[
    {'quarter': '2018-Q4', 'value': 2},
    {'quarter': '2019-Q1', 'value': 5},
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert to pairs and then zipObj with the field names:

```js
const { pipe, toPairs, map, zipObj } = R

const fn = pipe(
  toPairs,
  map(zipObj(['quarter', 'value']))
)

const data = {
  '2018-Q4': 2,
  '2019-Q1': 5
}

const result = fn(data)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.0/ramda.js"></script>
```